# Jquery função .data

Tags: jquery

Alguém me consegue esclarecer ou explicar me a diferença entre estas duas situações

```
$.data(this, 'timer')
```

Ou

```
$(this).data('timer');
```

Answer (score 0):

Fazem a mesma coisa. O jQuery permite fazer a mesma coisa de maneiras diferentes, este é um bom exemplo disso.

[Na documentação](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/) confirma-se isso:

> **Note:** This is a low-level method; a more convenient `.data()` is also available.
>
> **Nota:** Este é um método de baixo nível; um outro mais conveniente `.data()` também existe.